# Nodejs script not ending

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, okta

using the `client.getUser(:id|:login)` nodejs example at https://developer.okta.com/okta-sdk-nodejs/jsdocs/, I can **successfully** get the user details, however he script doesn’t “end” it just hangs after returning the user Information.

```
const okta = require('@okta/okta-sdk-nodejs');

const client = new okta.Client({
  orgUrl: 'https://dev-1234.oktapreview.com/'
  token: 'xYzabc'    // Obtained from Developer Dashboard
});

client.getUser('foo@bar.com')
.then(user => {
  console.log(user);
});
```

Do I need to “end” the connection or the promise or something?

Comment: show full script, please, - this code give 0 valuable information

Comment: That is the end of the script.  Above that code is simply requiring the module, and instantiate the `client`

Comment: The only reason why script is not finished - there is some tasks in a queue - if you remove this lines - what happens?

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk hi I have now included the full script

Comment: How do you run the script, actually?

Comment: This script appears to be reasonable. If node doesn't close, please report a bug in the sdk. Or does the `client` already have a method to close the connection? I couldn't find any in the documentation.

Comment: @WiktorZychla i do `node index.js` with the script save to `index.js`

Comment: @Bergi i cannot see or find a close (or synonym) for the client object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the issue here: =)

https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-nodejs/issues/86

Issue definitely in the sdk itself, not in the script you are running.

Looks like issue is here 
https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-nodejs/blob/master/src/memory-store.js#L22

Next workaround:

```
const okta = require('@okta/okta-sdk-nodejs');
const MemoryStore = require('@okta/okta-sdk-nodejs/src/memory-store');

const client = new okta.Client({
  cacheStore: new MemoryStore({
    expirationPoll:null
  }),
  orgUrl: 'https://dev-160519.oktapreview.com',
  token: '00s8yW7KiYpCOFRc8USWZWS4FgvQPSrnRli9QFFzZG',    // Obtained from Developer Dashboard,
});

client.getUser('foo@bar.com')
.then(user => {
  console.log(user);
}).catch(console.error);
```

works as expected

Comment: Linking the question to the github issue created by the question's OP won't help them much.

Comment: @WiktorZychla the question is just for developers of SDK

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk thank you for your help here and research, that’s so kind and helpful.. crazy :)